# is IIF function realeted to if in foxpro?

Tags: c#, database, visual-foxpro

`ExportCus   = IIF(GetControlValue("QBCUSTXFER", "Cnt", "Code") = "YES", .T., .F.)` 
can someone explain the diffrence between if and iif, i have tried if insted of iif and thats not working. help me

Comment: what means 'not working'?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, a.arun. Please consider [ask] and taking the [tour]. Then please improve your question, so we can help you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

`IIF` is sometimes called Immediate IF. It works much like the ternary `? :` operator in C, and other languages, or as a simplified `if-then-else`.

In you example, when the function call `GetControlValue("QBCUSTXFER", "Cnt", "Code")` returns "YES", `ExportCus` is assigned the value `.T.` (true), otherwise, it's assigned the value `.F.` (false).

Written as an `if` statement:

```
IF (GetControlValue("QBCUSTXFER", "Cnt", "Code") = "YES")
    ExportCus = .T.
ELSE
    ExportCus = .F.
ENDIF
```

Comment: Just to add a little more, IIF() is useful in places where you need an expression such as report fields. In regular code, you can do it either way. Personally, I think IF results in more readable code, except in cases where all three parameters of IIF() are short and simple.

Comment: and depending on the version VFP, ICASE() allows for multiple via such as ICASE( cond1, true, cond2, true, cond3, true, false )

Comment: Your answer could even be simplified one more level via..  ExportCus = GetControlValue( "QBCUSTXFER", "Cnt", "Code" ) = "YES".  Because the function returns YES or NO.  You are comparing  to "YES".  If it is the same, it returns TRUE directly to the variable.

Comment: I think IIF means Inline IF not immediate IF but not sure